# Detecting the version Tomcat Server (JSP/Servlet)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I developed an application using JSP/Servlets, it runs on tomcat server. I am using the [Tomcat Manager Commands](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html) to do some stuff like (deploy/undeploy... etc.). The problem is that the tomcat manager commands differ from version 6 to 7. Anyway, my application has to detect the version of the tomcat it is running on, and according to that change the commands in the application. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably make use of `getServerNumber()` method in `org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo` class in `catalina.jar` file.

Answer (score 0):

Windows:

```
java.exe -cp lib\catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
```

Linux:

```
java -cp lib/catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
```